# Calculate the sum of certain the_sub_fields

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to calculate the sum total from two custom sub-fields using ACF. The custom field is called 'repeater' and the sub-field is called 'space_avail'. I've tried the code below but it just lists the numbers individually rather than adding them up to a total. Please help.

```
<?php 
  $total = 0;
  while(the_repeater_field('repeater' )): 
      the_sub_field('space_avail' );
      $total += get_sub_field('space_avail' );
  endwhile; 
  echo $total;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
  $total = 0;
  while(the_repeater_field('repeater' )): 
      the_sub_field('space_avail' );
      $total += intval( get_sub_field('space_avail' ) );
  endwhile; 
  echo $total;
?>
```

Notice the `intval`. It tells php to consider the result as an number, not as a string

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the numbers are still being returned as a string.

Comment: It must be something else. Have you consulted the plugin's documentation to check if those functions are correct?

Comment: If no one here is able to help, post it on plugin's forum. You'll surely get an answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$total = 0;
while(have_rows('repeater')) : the_row();
    $space_avail = (int)get_sub_field('space_avail');
    $total += $space_avail;
endwhile;

echo $total;
```

Comment: wow! 2012 lol sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
the_sub_field('space_avail' );
```

This display's the string values.

[acf documentation repeater fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/)

```
    // loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

    // display a sub field value
    the_sub_field('sub_field_name');
```

so final code should be:

```
<?php 
  $total = 0;
  while(the_repeater_field('repeater' )):       
      $total += intval( get_sub_field('space_avail' ) );
  endwhile; 
  echo $total;
?>
```